# The Linux script does not run on MacOS

Tags: bash, macos

I have a script for work which runs fine on Ubuntu Virtual machine. I have recently switched to MacOS and while trying to run the same script I get the following error:

```bash
danyateran@MacBook-Air-Danya:~/restorator$ ./restorator.sh -V
/Users/danyateran/restorator/bin/functions.sh: line 1568: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
/Users/danyateran/restorator/bin/functions.sh: line 1568: `      ssh_conn "${SOURCE_SERVERNAME}" 'exec 2>&1; whmapi1 fetch_ssl_certificates_for_fqdns domains='${ssl_host}'; exit' &>> "${TMP_TRANSFER_DIR}/ssl_info_${ssl_host}.txt"'
```

While the syntax seems fine and as far as I know the MacOS has the same line endings as Linux, I have no idea what could be wrong. What is the cause of this MacOS-related problem and how can it be resolved?

Comment: You can format code correctly by putting four spaces at the start of each line. Or use backticks for inline code: \`code\` becomes `code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `&>>`, which appends both standard output and standard error to the same file, was introduced in bash version `4.0`. MacOS ships with bash version `3.2`.

You can change it to the more portable syntax:

```
>> "${TMP_TRANSFER_DIR}/ssl_info_${ssl_host}.txt" 2>&1
```

That's same thing, but will be understood by bash v3.2 (and newer, and `sh`).

However, there might be other things in the script which are not compatible, such as associative arrays, the `mapfile` built-in, various shell options, etc.

You can install a newer version of bash. The current version is `5.1`.

Comment: Thank you man, I have been struggling with this and your help just made my day